# Is there a multi function that call child folder of a dev path?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How to implement this example in kernel driver?
I looked in 'cdev'. but, the result is not convincing for this function using this example struct.

For example:

```
dev/test/on // this function is change status in test module

dev/test/changed "hello" // this function is change char value
```

I Looked "cdev" and some github. But, it is "/dev/test" one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found "sysfs"! Using this lib i can implement this example.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt